# Classification after dimension reduction with PCA

Tags: classification, data-science, pca, decision-tree

I have 60.000x784 training,
60.000 labels and

10.000x784 test, 10.000 test label data.

when i apply DecisionTreeClassifier (as show in the picture below). Classification score is %70.48

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPvVt.png)

but when i apply PCA with 32 components (0.751 variance) i get 0.1 score and i dont get why?

[code2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhMUa.png)

Comment: I think would be nice if you give a little sample of you data. I Would say to try to take a look at the covariance matrix of you data. Maybe you'r in some kind of floating point problem and need to give a little treatment on your data before use PCA. Try to apply some scaling on your data to make the PCA. Try to look at the covariance matrix of the data that you'r considering after apply the PCA too.

Comment: And finally, try to adjust the max depth of the tree. Becouse the tree depth is related with the number of features you are working with. Then, in the model with 784 features you should maybe try to increase the depth and a depth of 5 is a very small value for 32 features too.

Comment: After select the main features with PCA, if you have a depth of 5 you will use only 5 of these deatures to classify your data. Or maybe less, if you have a trong predictor in the he can be used in one or more 'nodes' of the tree. So you are throwing information in the trash using a depth of 5.